# Death by vaginal birth or C section?

Tags: reproduction

Now I have already set it so that these criteria are met when it comes to birth:

- At least 1 person by the mom, preferably 4 or more
- Vertex birth: any position is fine
- Breech birth: Prone position and other positions that put
  pressure on the back are not fine
- Transverse birth: any position that puts pressure on either the
  sides or the back isn't okay

Here are the 3 types of birth:

[image]

Now my humanoids prefer vaginal birth when possible.

Even for big babies like this one:

[image]

They prefer vaginal birth so much that they typically don't do a C section.

But there are some situations in which it would be C section or death.

But my Kepler Bb humanoids don't have precise surgical tools so a C section could just as easily cause death as vaginal birth.

So their C section would be crude and I wouldn't be surprised if this crude C section causes uterine rupture with subsequent pregnancies.

Plus, they don't have anesthesia and the pain meds they do have are not safe at the dose required for labor pains, much less labor pains + surgery.

This is a very difficult decision. On the one hand, vaginal birth could lead to maternal and neonatal death. On the other hand a C section can lead to maternal death and if there are no other lactating women or the lactating women are too busy with their own babies, the baby could starve to death(no formula is available to replace breastmilk).

So in situations of crude C section or extremely difficult vaginal birth, if the mom dies, should she die from a C section or from a difficult vaginal birth? I personally think vaginal birth is better because it at least proves that later on, vaginal birth in any situation might be safe.

**But what do you think? Should the mom die in a difficult vaginal birth to prove that later on vaginal birth might be safe 100% of the time or should she risk uterine rupture and death from a C section to save the baby?**

Answer (score 4):

Even today, there is still a certain amount of risk with vaginal birth, even if the baby is in a good position.  The position of the placenta and umbilical cord also play a role.

There is placenta previa (I think that's the spelling) where the placent comes out before the kid.  if steps are not taken to get the child out very quickly, the blood and oxygen flow to the baby are disrupted, leading to possible death within a matter of minutes.  There is also a (thankfully) rare times when the umbilical can be wrapped around the baby's neck and shoulder, pinching off blood supply during delivery.  So Vaginal Birth is not 100% safe for the child.

On the flip side, medieval C-sections were fatal often as a result of infection, if the mother didn't die of blood loss or other complications.

So your hypothetical mother has a choice to make based on philosophy and instinct.  I would guess that a pregnant mother would almost always base the decision on whether or not the child will survive...period. Throughout history, even mothers who faced the prospect of certain death themselves, would choose the life of the child over their own.  When you add societal pressures to generate heirs, it makes this even more certain.

It's not just society either.  We humans are, by inclination, pack animals.  The next generation surviving gives us an evolutionary edge when the pack will care for our young, even if the birth mother dies.  It's why you will see dogs help rear puppies (and sometimes other species young entirely) that are not theirs, biologically speaking.  It's instinctual.

Comment: This is the decision about child birth faced by the human specie for most of its history. Modern medicine has given us respite (mostly) from difficult decisions like this. Plus one for tackling a difficult topic.